# Spring REST API: handle a http error

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-rest

I develop a Spring API and for any Exception or error case I want to send to a client a formal json answer.

I have already read aboud `@ExceptionHandler` and implemented it. But there is at least one case when the application throws an HTTP error without a corresponding Exception, hence I cannot generate a corresponding json answer for it.

When the API request is not supported (for example, I add an integer number to the path in the post request) the client receives:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
  <title>Error 405</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>HTTP ERROR: 405</h2>
  <p>
      Problem accessing /a/wrong/path/67. Reason:
      <pre>Request method 'POST' not supported</pre>
   </p>
   <hr/>
   <i>
      <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
   </i>
 </body>
</html>
```

and nothing in JSON format, which i little bit breakes the integrity of my application.

Is there something like an HTTP error handler for Spring? How can I generat a json answer for such a case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom handling for 405 error with Spring Web MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237984/custom-handling-for-405-error-with-spring-web-mvc)

Comment: For handling request errors, use filter to handle requests, and filterize the request first and catch any exception you want.