# How to catch HTTP 405 "Method Not Allowed" exception using @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-405

I created a REST application and added a class to handle exceptions:

```
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.foxminded.university.api.controller")
public class ApiGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final String API_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION = "REST API reached unhandled exception: %s";
    private static final HttpStatus internalServerError = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handle(Exception e) {
        ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail = new ExceptionDetail(
            String.format(API_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage()),
            internalServerError,
            ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionDetail, internalServerError);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(
        TypeMismatchException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail = new ExceptionDetail(
            String.format(API_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION, ex.getMessage()),
            internalServerError,
            ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionDetail, internalServerError);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail = new ExceptionDetail(
            String.format(API_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage()),
            internalServerError,
            ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()),
            e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionDetail, internalServerError);
    }
}
```

When I send the wrong post request via postman http://localhost:8080/api/groups/jkjk instead of http://localhost:8080/api/groups

It throws me an exception that I can't catch initializing when debugging, neither in the ApiGlobalExceptionHandler class nor in the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1604171144423,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/groups/jkjk"
}
```

All other exceptions I can catch. How do I catch this exception to add custom handling?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the explanation here [Custom handling for 405 error with Spring Web MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237984/custom-handling-for-405-error-with-spring-web-mvc)

It says `The reason your @ExceptionHandler annotated method never catches your exception is because these ExceptionHandler annotated methods are invoked after a successful Spring controller handler mapping is found. However, your exception is raised before that.`

And the solution is to extends not from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class, but from DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver and override it handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported method.

Comment: This will returns view. In your case it should be `@ResponseBody` that you expect.

Comment: If you check the code of DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver, method handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported returns just empty view. The main job there is `"response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, ex.getMessage());"`. So, actually it configures error for response, but not preparing the view. Could you specify, why do you dislike the answer, what is you doubt?

Comment: But, don't you have to error content to the response body?

Comment: As I understood from the post I mentioned (by the way it's already solved problem), for post operation, that has wrong type of argument, it's not possible to rewrite default error handling using @ErrorHandling annotation at all... Correct me if I'm wrong. So, maybe there is another way, but i didn't find any other explanation and, as I told, I'm not able to catch this exception with you approach... maybe i'm doing wrong... but, when you're debugging your code for overriden handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported method, are you able to stop on break point for return statement?

Comment: Just to specify the problem, there is a rest controller with mapping to some entity list and there is mapped post method, that creates new entity when you send post request for URI like "site.com\entities". But when you send post for "site.com\entities\abc" it gives an error response with 405 status, that i'm not able to catch.

Comment: wrong type of argument throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and what is `@ErrorHandling`? For me it works well. If it worked your way, that's fine. I am just suggesting not to go with the `DefaultHandler`. Read the comments on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a new method to with `MethodNotAllowedException` in its signature.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodNotAllowedException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodNotAllowedExceptionException(MethodNotAllowedException ex) {
    return buildResponseEntity(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, null, null, ex.getMessage(), null);
}

private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, HttpHeaders headers, Integer internalCode, String message, List<Object> errors) {
    ResponseBase response = new ResponseBase() //A generic ResponseBase class
            .success(false)
            .message(message)
            .resultCode(internalCode != null ? internalCode : status.value())
            .errors(errors != null
                    ? errors.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())
                    : null);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>((Object) response, headers, status);
}
```

You can customize the `buildResponseEntity`as you please.

**UPDATED**

I revisited my answer since it didn't meet your requirement. So, it follows like this:

I send post request for a method that accepts `GET`. This will fire *Request method 'POST' not supported* as printed below.

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.Looking up handler method for path /v1/user/profile/1
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ethGlobalExceptionHandler'

In this case, there is no need to add
`@ExceptionHandler(value = HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)`.

In fact if you do so, the following error will be thrown (since it is already handled),

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]:....
```

So, the solution will be:

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return buildResponseEntity(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, headers, null, ex.getMessage(), Arrays.asList(""));
}
```

Comment: But why it's not catched by handle method with @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) ? I was expected it should catch all that wasn't catched by ResponseEntityExceptionHandler methods...

Comment: You are extending from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` which provides handling for standard Spring MVC exceptions only.

Comment: I added an exception handler to the rest controller with the following annotation `@ExceptionHandler (MethodNotAllowedException.class)` but the problem still exists. The cursor does not jump to this method when debugging, and the response is the default.

Comment: I'm not sure that I completely understood all your points, but here are my doubts: 1. You wrote "I send post request for a method that accepts GET. This will fire Request method 'POST' not supported as printed below." It accepts both get and post. Get for receiving list of entities and post to create new entity. 2. You wrote "In fact if you do so, the following error will be thrown (since it is already handled)". For extending from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, I was speaking about MethodNotAllowedException.class, but not HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class. There were no errors...

Comment: Check this short description https://evertpot.com/http/405-method-not-allowed